# How to get the min value of a key based upon the value of another key in a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of dictionaries that looks like -

```
"produce": [
    {
        "name": "carrot",
        "type": "vegetable",
        "price": 10.0,
        "units": "KG"
    },
    {
        "name": "potato",
        "type": "stem tuber",
        "price": 2.0,
        "units": "KG"
    },
    {
        "type": "fruit",
        "price": 5.0,
        "units": "KG"
    }
]
```

I need to get the lowest price if type is either a fruit or a stem tuber. I get a Type error -

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

I have the following code -

```
for m in produce:
    if ((m.get('type') == 'stem tuber') or 
        (m.get('type') == 'fruit')
       ):
       fPrice = min(m['price'])
```

I get the error on `fPrice = min(m['price'])`.

I am at a loss how to fix this. Can someone help please? I need to get the lowest price amongst `5.0` and `2.0`, so the answer should be `2.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because you're giving individual numbers to `min()`, and `min` wants an `iterable` such as a `list`. How do we fix this?
Let's say you have a dictionary like so:

```
mydict = {"produce": [
    {
        "name": "carrot",
        "type": "vegetable",
        "price": 10.0,
        "units": "KG"
    },
    {
        "name": "potato",
        "type": "stem tuber",
        "price": 2.0,
        "units": "KG"
    },
    {
        "type": "fruit",
        "price": 5.0,
        "units": "KG"
    }
]}
```

Take

```
produce = mydict['produce']
```

Time to build a list comprehension!

You want to iterate over the items in the list `produce`.

```
[for m in produce]
```

Then, you want to check if the type is in some set of strings.

```
[for m in produce if m.get('type') in {'stem tuber', 'fruit'}]
```

Then, you want to extract its price. If no price exists, 0 seems like a reasonable default!

```
[m.get('price', 0) for m in produce if m.get('type') in {'stem tuber', 'fruit'}]
```

Then you want to find the min

```
min([m.get('price', 0) for m in produce if m.get('type') in {'stem tuber', 'fruit'}])
```

You can also get rid of the square brackets around `m.get(...)` and it becomes a generator expression, as [wjandrea's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64163296/4518341) below explains!

Re.  *"How do I handle a situation where there are no records with type stem tuber or fruit in the list comprehension"*:

You can add another item to the list like so:

```
min([m.get('price', 0) for m in produce if m.get('type') in {'stem tuber', 'fruit'}] + [-1])
```

Presumably, nothing costs -1 (0 is the minimum).
Then if you get -1, you know nothing matched.

Comment: Thank you for explaining in a step wise methodical manner. appreciate it!

Comment: FWIW, you can remove the brackets at the last step, since `min` can accept a generator expression. I did that in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64163296/4518341).

Comment: @wjandrea I was about to add that to my answer when I saw you already wrote one about it, so I just added a link in mine to yours.

Comment: Thank you guys!  Very helpful. Can I ask a follow up question? How do I handle a situation where there are no records with type stem tuber or fruit in the list comprehension?

Comment: Thank you sir! I figured it out using @wjandrea suggestion but was also interested in knowing how to handle it in list comprehension like you just mentioned.

Comment: @JMushiana I updated my answer to include error handling

Answer (score 1):

You're feeding individual prices to `min`, which doesn't work. Instead, feed an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) of prices. You could use a generator expression:

```
low = min(
    m['price']
    for m in produce
    if m.get('type') in {'stem tuber', 'fruit'}
    )
print(low)  # -> 2.0
```

If it helps you understand better, this is like using a list comprehension then feeding the list to `min`, but more direct.

```
prices = [
    m['price']
    for m in produce
    if m.get('type') in {'stem tuber', 'fruit'}
    ]
low = min(prices)
print(low)  # -> 2.0
```

---

To handle the case of no matching prices, wrap the `min` section in a `try` block and use `except ValueError`. Just for example, let's use your existing data but say you're looking for the lowest price on a gourd:

```
try:
    low = min(
        m['price']
        for m in produce
        if m.get('type') in {'gourd'}
        )
except ValueError:
    print('No matching prices')
    import sys
    sys.exit(1)
```

See [Handling Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) in the Python tutorial.

BTW, if you need better error message printing, look into [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html).